# Close Excel associated with a particular file name

Tags: excel, vba

After a bunch of processing, I save my Excel spreadsheet with a script-defined name and a user-chosen path. In other words, I know exactly where the file is.

I want to close down Excel. If I do

```
Workbook.Close
```

...the instance of Excel will hang around. If I do

```
Excel.Application.quit
```

...it might affect other instances of Excel I have open.
Given I know exactly which Excel I want to close, can I close the workbook AND the associated instance in a single step, without a lot of testing for other workbooks or instances? TIA

Comment: `Workbooks("name_of_workbook").Close`?

Comment: You can create a new instance and assign a variable to that then do `xlapp.quit` from there.

Comment: Where is this code running? In the same Excel instance as the workbook, or a different one?  If a different one, how you you first get the reference to the workbook?  There's a lot of context missing here.

Comment: @CLR You would think so, but that gives me a "Subscript out of range"

Comment: @TimWilliams The code runs in Word and creates and populates an Excel spreadsheet based on comments and revisions in a given Word document.

Comment: If that's the case then you already created an Excel Application object in your Word VBA (or got a reference to it using GetObject maybe).  So you can call the `Quit` method on that reference.  Calling Quit on a specific Excel `Application` object won't affect any other instances of Excel which might be open.

Answer (score 0):

If you already have the Workbook Object, you can access the Application that it is running within using `Workbook.Application`. The `.Parent` property also returns the object that the current object is a member of, which for Workbooks, is also the `Application`.

So either of the following will close the specific Excel App that is running the target workbook:

```vb
'Given that TargetWorkbook is a valid Workbook Object
TargetWorkbook.Application.Quit
TargetWorkbook.Parent.Quit
```